# How to find the nearest neighboring elements of an td using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery, am working on small table based game here i have to find the neighboring elements around an TD in a table .

EX:

1 2 3

4 **5** 6

7 8 9

there are three rows in a table , if i consider 5 is my element then how to find neighbor elements for 5 (neighbors:2 4 6 8) ???

Comment: Sibling selectors are easy. What's more challenging is getting elements from sibling rows based on index, but that's been covered well on SO, too.

Comment: use `closest()` method for [more  click](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: @Pranavc, I don't think that is going to work.

Comment: closest select first nearest one only...... for all u can use `siblings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use traversal methods like `next, prev` and selector method like `eq` along with `add` to develop a solution

```
var $td = $('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)'); //current td = 5

var index = $td.index(), $tr =$td.parent();
var $nbrs = $td.prev().add($td.next()).add($tr.prev().find('td').eq(index)).add($tr.next().find('td').eq(index));
console.log($nbrs.get())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MNV55)

A more detailed approach

```
var $td = $('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)'); //current td = 5

var index = $td.index(), $tr =$td.parent();
var $nbrs = $td.prev(); //find the previous td
$nbrs = $nbrs.add($td.next());//find the next td
$nbrs = $nbrs.add($tr.prev().find('td').eq(index));//find the td with the same index in previous row
$nbrs = $nbrs.add($tr.next().find('td').eq(index));//find the td with the same index in next row

$nbrs.css('color', 'red')
console.log($nbrs.get())
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Arun P Johny , This is what exactly i wanted .

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, without jQuery:

```
var row = cell.parentNode;
var table_body = row.parentNode;
var neighbors = [];

if (cell.cellIndex > 0) {
    neighbors.push(rows.cells[cell.cellIndex - 1]);
}

if (row.rowIndex > 0) {
    neighbors.push(table_body.rows[row.rowIndex - 1].cells[cell.cellIndex]);
}

if (cell.cellIndex < rows.cells.length - 1) {
    neighbors.push(rows.cells[cell.cellIndex + 1]);
}

if (row.rowIndex < table_body.rows.length - 1) {
    neighbors.push(table_body.rows[row.rowIndex + 1].cells[cell.cellIndex]);
}
```

Comment: +1. Much better than any of the jQuery solutions below.

Comment: where do you define "rows" and "cells"?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require too much, for the vertical neighbors however you're going to need the index of 5 (which is 1) -- assuming `$(this)` represents the `td` which contains `5`:

```
var index  = $(this).index(),
    left   = $(this).prev("td").text(),
    right  = $(this).next("td").text(),
    top    = $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").find("td:eq(" + index + ")").text(),
    bottom = $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find("td:eq(" + index + ")").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are performing inside the `click` event,

You can get

4 by,

```
$(this).prev().text()
```

5 by,

```
$(this).next().text()
```

2 by,

```
$(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td').eq($(this).index()).text()
```

8 by,

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').eq($(this).index()).text()
```

But keep in mind that, The code may return `undefined`, if you are clicking on the edges.